# Annotating/labelling areas in a plot

Tags: r, plot, polygon

I've the following graph:

[image: Graph]

The graph (except the red letters) is generated by the following code:

```
boundary12 <- c(0.01, 0.005, 0.002, 0.001)
boundary23 <- c(0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01)
boundary34 <- c(0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.55)

plot(boundary12, type="lines", ylim=c(0,1), xlab="Pollution level", ylab="Probability of event")
lines(boundary23)
lines(boundary34)
```

Questions:

1) If I generate many graphs, is there any way to semi-automatically put the red letters in?

2) Is there a way to color the regions e.g. region 1 is blue, region 2 is yellow, region 3 is green?

Comment: See `?polygon` for filling regions, though ggplot's `geom_area` might be easier to use if you don't mind switching plotting paradigms.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend separating your questions. I'd maybe write up a nice solution to Q2 using `geom_area`, but I don't really want to tackle Q1, so I'm not answering right now. Better to deal with one question at a time.

Comment: And you might want to add more detail regarding the red letters. Why are they at different x positions? Would it be okay to just put them all at x = 1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations can be placed automatically by calculating the polygon centroids.

```
plot(boundary12, type="n", ylim=c(0,1), xlab="Pollution level",
  ylab="Probability of event")

poly12 <- data.frame(x=c(1:4, 4:1), y=c(boundary12, rev(boundary23)))
poly23 <- data.frame(x=c(1:4, 4:1), y=c(boundary23, rev(boundary34)))
poly34 <- data.frame(x=c(1:4, 4:1), y=c(boundary34, rep(1, 4)))

polygon(poly12, border="#00000066", col="skyblue")
polygon(poly23, border="#00000066", col="gold")
polygon(poly34, border="#00000066", col="darkolivegreen3")

library(maps)
centroid <- maps:::centroid.polygon

p12 <- centroid(poly12)
p23 <- centroid(poly23)
p34 <- centroid(poly34)

textcoor <- rbind(p12, p23, p34)
textcoor[1, 1] <- textcoor[1 ,1] * 0.8 # to smooch nr1 a bit to the left

text(textcoor, labels=1:3, col="darkblue", cex=1.2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution using the polygon function to perform the fill.  This will need to be extended for a more general solution to handle more points and a variable upper limit.

```
boundary12 <- c(0.01, 0.005, 0.002, 0.001)
boundary23 <- c(0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01)
boundary34 <- c(0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.55)

plot(boundary12, type="lines", ylim=c(0,1), xlab="Pollution level", ylab="Probability of event")
lines(boundary23)
lines(boundary34)
#create polygons and fill
polygon(x=c(1:4, 4:1), y=c(boundary12, rev(boundary23)), col="blue")
polygon(x=c(1:4, 4:1), y=c(boundary23, rev(boundary34)), col="yellow")
polygon(x=c(1:4, 4,1 ), y=c(boundary34, c(1,1)), col="green")
```